# How to put json data into html

Tags: javascript, html, json, cordova

I am trying to use REST webservice in a phonegap application. Here is the code for that -

```
function myFunction() {
    alert("Hello World");
    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url : 'http://api.glassdoor.com/api/api.htm?t.p=19754&t.k=IFuttOxoRG&userip=127.0.0.1&useragent=&format=json&v=1.1&action=jobs&q=&l=San+Francisco&pn=1&ps=50',
        crossDomain : true,
        contentType: "application/json",
        success : function(data){
            alert("got data");
            for( var i=0; i<5; i++) {
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = data[i].occupation;
            }
        },
        error : function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus, errorThrown) {     
          alert("error"); 


        }
    });
    alert("here");
}
```

When I enter that url in the browser [this](http://api.glassdoor.com/api/api.htm?t.p=19754&t.k=IFuttOxoRG&userip=127.0.0.1&useragent=&format=json&v=1.1&action=jobs&q=&l=San%20Francisco&pn=1&ps=50) is what I see. How do I print all the joblistings onto my webpage? 
If I do document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = data; I see [Object][Object] on the screen. Using my current code I see nothing. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand the structure of JSON and then navigate it. Try [here](http://json.org/) or [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON).

The array of job listings appears to be at `data.response.jobListings`, but each one is an object that you must decide how you want to convert into HTML. The simplest way is to turn it back to JSON with `JSON.stringify`, but that won't be very user-friendly.

```
success : function(data){
    var listingJSON = JSON.stringify(data.response.jobListings);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = listingJSON;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. This should log the job titles to the console. You can append them to the document instead, but also try logging the 'listings' object in my code for you reference, to see how it is structured. See how I accessed the jobTitle with listings[i].jobTitle, you can to the same for other fields such as location

```
success : function(data){
    var listings = data.response.jobListings;  
    console.log(listings)
    for(i=0; i<listings.length; i++){
        console.log(listings[i].jobTitle)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON Data can be rendered as a String , but you need to have json parser to parse the string.

**jQuery.parseJSON()**

Answer (score -1):

You need to parse the string into a javascript object, use JSON.parse(data)

```
function myFunction() {
    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url : 'http://api.glassdoor.com/api/api.htm?t.p=19754&t.k=IFuttOxoRG&userip=127.0.0.1&useragent=&format=json&v=1.1&action=jobs&q=&l=San+Francisco&pn=1&ps=50',
        crossDomain : true,
        contentType: "application/json",
        success : function(data){

            // turn the string response into a javascript object!

            data = JSON.parse(data)
            for( var i=0; i<5; i++) {
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = data[i].occupation;
            }
        },
        error : function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus, errorThrown) {     
          alert("error"); 
    }
});
alert("here");
```

}

Comment: If `data` weren't already an object, it wouldn't display as "[Object]".